# JavaFX binding image property to image (MVC)

Tags: image, model-view-controller, javafx, imageview

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682881/binding-image-in-javafx) question while searching for an answer. But it doesn't seem to be a solution for my case.

In my viewcontroller I've the following:

```
public void setModel(CarcassonneModel model) {
   this.model = model;
   ivHoveringTile.imageProperty().bind(getImage(model.board.getActiveTile().getFilename()));
}

private ObjectProperty<Image> getImage(String filename) {
        File file = new File("src/carcassonneapplicatie/resources/tiles/" + filename + ".png");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());

        ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(image);

        return imageProperty;
    }
```

However, the displayed image doesn't change when I change the filename in my model using an action event. I've got other bindings for my labels and they seem to work perfectly, except for this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
someProperty.bind(someOtherProperty);
```

then `someProperty` is updated automatically whenever `someOtherProperty.set(...)` is invoked.

In your code `someOtherProperty` is the `ObjectProperty<Image>` you create in your `getImage()` method. Since you don't even retain a reference to this property, there's no possible way you can ever call `set(...)` on it. So the image in `ivHoveringTile` never updates.

You need to bind to an observable object in the model, representing the actual value that may change.